# Pass dynamic Type to Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, list, reflection, types

Basically I want to pass Type which is calculated on run time to List< T>:

```
Type someType = GetSomeType()
List<someType> myList = new List<someType>();
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**
[The following  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) looks similar however is different since I want Generics with Type and not GenericMethod. As suggested in other comments there is GenericType however that still not answer my question fully

Comment: Also @PavelAnikhouski `MakeGenericMethod` is definitely not the right thing to use. You probably meant [`MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to instantiate a generic type and create an object of that type at runtime, however it is difficult to do anything useful with the result.

Here is a static method to instantiate a generic type:

```
public static class GenericExt {
    public static object newListOfType(Type aType) {
        var openListType = typeof(List<>);
        var closedListType = openListType.MakeGenericType(aType);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(closedListType);
    }

}
```

And you could call it with:

```
var x = GenericExt.newListOfType(typeof(string));
```

**Do not be fooled.** The type of `x` is `object`, not `List<string>`. It is not possible *at compile time* to know the type of `x`, and so you can't call e.g. `x.Add()` because `object` does not have an `Add` method.

UPDATE: As pointed out by @EtiennedeMartel, you could return an `IList` and work with that like a C# 1.0 `List` object.